# In Wristcutters: A Love Story who do the police work for?

Tags: plot-explanation, wristcutters-a-love-story

In *Wristcutters: A Love Story*, which I have to say is my all-time favorite movie, who do the police work for?

The only apparent government is the People In Charge (P.I.C.), who are revealed to basically be angels of some sort. They apparently hold the only real organized power, as when they shutdown a suicide cult.

However there were multiple normal human police who had also killed themselves in the film. One arrested Mikal for vandalism. Did they work for the P.I.C.? If not, where did they get their authority?